# How to use grep and regex to extract information within specific tag

Tags: ios, regex, linux, curl, grep

I try to extract the information within a tag:

```
<div class="rpt_price rpt_price_1">THE TEXT</div>
```

using this command:

```
t=$(curl -v --silent http://somewebsite.info/ 2>&1 | grep -E "^<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">.*</div>$"); echo $t
```

which should return the `THE TEXT`, however it echoed nothing. What is my mistake? Thanks in advance!

Comment: grep and regex is entirely wrong tool to use to parse html... and if regex is good enough for your case, you need `grep -oP` which is not available for you... so then use `sed` or `awk`... grep is primarily for finding not text manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works using:

```
grep -Po "<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">\K(.*)(?=</div>$)"
```

The `-P` and `-o` options are described here at [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13472). The `\K` is also explained very well on [unix stackexchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/179665/group-matching-with-grep-includes-extra-characters).

The usage of `\K(.*)` will ouput only the match and the following text. With `(?=...$)` i exclude the rest of the text.

**Test:**

```
echo "<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">THE TEXT</div>" | grep -Po "<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">\K(.*)(?=</div>$)"
```

**Output:**

```
THE TEXT
```

---

Another possibility is to use `perl` directly, explanations are [here on superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/416419/perl-for-matching-with-regular-expressions-in-terminal):

```
perl -ne 'print $1 if /\<div class="rpt_price rpt_price_1">(.*?)\<\/div>/s'
```

**Test:**

```
echo "<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">THE TEXT</div>" | perl -ne 'print $1 if /\<div class="rpt_price rpt_price_1">(.*?)\<\/div>/s'
```

**Output:**

```
THE TEXT
```

Comment: I did try the parameter `-Po` but I get the error `grep: Support for the -P option is not compiled into this --disable-perl-regexp binary` since I'm in iOS environment (terminal)

Comment: @GregorIsack: Do you have access to `perl`, if so see my extended answer.

Comment: I just installed `perl` on my device and it works perfectly! But perl package is consuming my device's limited storage capacity. I'll mark this as an answer if there is no better answer. Thank you for the help!

Comment: You're welcome! I see no other way as `grep` can't extract a string out of an expression without using the perl opion (`-P`) because their wouldn't be lookahead options available (`(?=...$)`) without that. But maybe some other have a solution that I don't know ;-D.

Comment: Can I ask a question 'cause I'm not familiar with `perl`, in your example you use pipe to transfer the output, can I assign a variable to the source and feed it into perl, if yes, how do I do it? For example, `source=$(echo something); perl $source`

Comment: I would do it with echo and pipe that: `source=$(echo something); echo $source | perl ...`.

Comment: Ahhh why I didn't think of that! Thanks for being so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

You have not escaped the last `/` in your `</div>`.

The correct regex should be the following:

`^<div class=\"rpt_price rpt_price_1\">.*<\/div>$`

For regex, [this](https://regex101.com/) is a great tool to test what your results will be when you are creating one.

Comment: Still nothing return, though I'm sure the regex after your correction works! I starts to suspect the `curl`

Comment: the regex should be fine, it matches the thing you are searching for. Let me check the curl. What website are you targeting?

Comment: This regex works but it won't exract just the part: `THE TEXT` but the whole expression.